# Highlight search word in Excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel

Below is the code to search for words in excel and highlight them. But the problem is the whole range is getting highlighted instead of the particular word.Please help

```
for (int i = 1; i < xmlnode.Count; i++)
{
    XmlAttributeCollection xmlattrc = xmlnode[i].Attributes;
    object text = xmlnode[i].FirstChild.InnerText;
    string str;
    int rCnt = 0;
    int cCnt = 0;
    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet1;
    Excel.Range range;
    xlWorkSheet1 = (Excel.Worksheet)doc1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    range = xlWorkSheet1.get_Range("A1","A10");

    for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
    {
        for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
        {
            str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value2; 

            string[] words = str.Split(' ');


            if (str == text.ToString())
            {
                range.Font.Bold = 1;
                range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);                                        
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the operations on a single cell. Try this code in your if-statement:

```
if (str == text.ToString())
{
  var cell = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range);
  cell.Font.Bold = 1;
  cell.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red); 
}
```